# Numpyro AR(1) mean switching model sampling incongrouencies

Tags: python, jax, pyro, numpyro

I'm trying to estimate an AR(1) process `y` with a switching mean according to a latent state `S` =0,1 that evolves as a markov process with fixed transition probabilities (as in [here](https://direct.mit.edu/books/book/3265/State-Space-Models-with-Regime-SwitchingClassical)). In short, it takes the form:

```
y_t - mu_{0/1} = phi * (y_{t-1} - mu_{0/1})+ epsilon_t
```

where `mu_0` would be used if state_t = 0 and mu_1 if state_t =1.
I'm using jax/numpyro with DiscreteHMCGibbs (although normal NUTS with latent state enumeration yields the same result) but I can't seem to have the sampler work properly. From all diagnostics I run, it seems that all hyperparameters are stuck at initialization value, and summary returns accordingly with all std==0. Here below I have a MWE that reproduces my problem. Is there an obvious mistake I am making in the implementation?

MWE:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
import numpyro
import numpyro.distributions as dist
from numpyro.contrib.control_flow import scan
from numpyro.infer import MCMC, NUTS,DiscreteHMCGibbs
from jax import random, pure_callback
import jax
import numpy as np

def generate_synthetic_data(T=100, mu=[0, 5], phi=0.5, sigma=1.0, p=np.array([[0.95, 0.05], [0.1, 0.9]])):
    states = np.zeros(T, dtype=np.int32)
    y = np.zeros(T)
    current_state = np.random.choice([0, 1], p=[0.5, 0.5])
    states[0] = current_state
    y[0] = np.random.normal(mu[current_state], sigma)

    for t in range(1, T):
        current_state = np.random.choice([0, 1], p=p[current_state,:])
        states[t] = current_state
        y[t] = np.random.normal(mu[current_state] + phi * (y[t-1] - mu[current_state]), sigma)

    return y, states


def mean_switching_AR1_model(y):
    T = len(y)
    phi = numpyro.sample('phi', dist.Normal(0, 1))
    sigma = numpyro.sample('sigma', dist.Exponential(1))
    
    
    with numpyro.plate('state_plate', 2):
        mu = numpyro.sample('mu', dist.Normal(0, 5))
        p = numpyro.sample('p', dist.Dirichlet(jnp.ones(2)))

    probs_init = numpyro.sample('probs_init', dist.Dirichlet(jnp.ones(2)))
    s_0 = numpyro.sample('s_0', dist.Categorical(probs_init))

    def transition_fn(carry, y_t):
        prev_state = carry
        state_probs = p[prev_state]
        state = numpyro.sample('state', dist.Categorical(state_probs))

        mu_state = mu[state]
        y_mean = mu_state + phi * (y_t - mu_state)
        y_next = numpyro.sample('y_next', dist.Normal(y_mean, sigma), obs=y_t)
        return state, (state, y_next)

    _ , (signal, y)=scan(transition_fn, s_0, y[:-1], length=T-1)
    return (signal, y)

# Synthetic data generation
T = 1000
mu_true = [0, 3]
phi_true = 0.5
sigma_true = 0.25
transition_matrix_true = np.array([[0.95, 0.05], [0.1, 0.9]])
y, states_true = generate_synthetic_data(T, mu=mu_true, phi=phi_true, sigma=sigma_true, p=transition_matrix_true)


rng_key = random.PRNGKey(0)
nuts_kernel = NUTS(mean_switching_AR1_model)
gibbs_kernel = DiscreteHMCGibbs(nuts_kernel, modified=True)

# Run MCMC
mcmc = MCMC(gibbs_kernel, num_samples=1000, num_warmup=1000)
mcmc.run(rng_key, y=y)
mcmc.print_summary()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out there was indeed a pretty obvious mistake in the sense that I was not correctly carrying down `y_{t-1}` as part of the state variables. The following corrected transition functions yield the intended result without problems.

```
def transition_fn(carry, y_curr):
    prev_state, y_prev = carry
    state_probs = p[prev_state]
    state = numpyro.sample('state', dist.Categorical(state_probs))

    mu_state = mu[state]
    y_mean = mu_state + phi * (y_prev - mu_state)
    y_curr = numpyro.sample('y_curr', dist.Normal(y_mean, sigma), obs=y_curr)
    return (state, y_curr), (state, y_curr)

_, (signal, y) = scan(transition_fn, (s_0, y[0]), y[1:], length=T-1)
```